# What may be the issue for the files and issues not getting updated in the Mantis BT Repository->Manage?

Tags: gitlab, mantis

Using Gitlab integrated with Mantis BT
Mantis BT -> Repositories -> Manage, when clicked on import the latest data, data is getting imported and the changesets value is getting updated but the statistics files and issues values are not getting updated

Issues:
What may be the issue for the values not getting updated?
Does it require any change in MantisSourcePlugin code?

Comment: What do you meant by statistics files and issues values? Are you asking about associating a changeset to an issue?

Comment: Associating a changeset to an issue is resolved. Mantis BT -> Repository ->